# main pom.xml not deployed when having submodules

Tags: java, module, pom.xml, multi-module

i hav a project with 2 sub modules where my main "pom.xml" does not have code (yet) i deploy to my local repository both deployed but the main is not deployed

when a new user try to "mvn install" to get the submodule it shows that the "com.zzzzz.main" is not found

-- **Could not resolve dependencies for project**
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.zzzzz.main == Could not find artifact

my main pom.xml is:

```
  <groupId>com.zzzzz.main</groupId>
  <artifactId>main</artifactId>
  <version>1-beta</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>



...
<modules>
<module>app1</module>
<module>app1-daq</module>
</modules>
```

my submodule are:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.zzzzz.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <version>1-beta</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>app1</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <name>app1</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

log

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] main ............................................... SUCCESS [  0.001 s]
[INFO] app1 ............................................... SUCCESS [  1.414 s]
[INFO] app1-daq ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.288 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS



$ find | grep jar
./app1/target/app1.jar
./app1-daq/target/app1-daq.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify modules in your parent pom using < modules> tag 
Parent pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>child1</module>
    <module>child2</module>
</modules></project>
```

child pom

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <artifactId>child1</artifactId>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>

    </project>
```

Comment: I added them ... still same result

Comment: the modules are deployed properly tho

Comment: @yenk  can you please share verbose logs. I tried same structure at my end its working.